# Executing Cmd command in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, cmd

i want to compile an input text and create the .exe file using a managed bean and a page .xhtml . However the Creation of file went Ok and the creation of .exe dosn't work
here is the managed bean code :

```
package Servlets;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
@ManagedBean(name = "fichier", eager = true)
public class Fichier implements Serializable{
private String code;
private String error;




public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public String getError() {
    return error;
}
 public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}



public void compile() throws IOException 
{


    File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\Rad1\\test.c");
    PrintWriter ecrivain;
    ecrivain =  new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter(file)));
    ecrivain.println(code);
            System.out.print("ecrivain");
    ecrivain.close();
    try {  
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
         String[] cmd={"cmd.exe","/C gcc C:\\Users\\Rad1\\test.c -o C:\\Users\\Rad1\\test.exe"};
         Process p = runtime.exec(cmd,null,null );
                     System.out.print("boucle try");
          try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            try {

            String line=null;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                 error =error+ line + "\n";
                }
            } finally {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();

        }


        } 
    catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("erreur d'execution"); }




}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the generated exceptions? Check **catalina.out** file. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to make the "/C" a seperate argument:

```
String[] cmd={"cmd.exe","/C", "gcc C:\\Users\\Rad1\\test.c -o C:\\Users\\Rad1\\test.exe"};
```

That's the way it's supposed to work, but I'm on linux, can't test Cmd right now.

Edit: why do you have the extra null's on the runtime.exec(cmd, null, null)?

Comment: dosn't work ! it still create the test.c file and dosn't create the .exe

Comment: it worked when i was working with jsp and servlets and these are argument i don't need , i just need the cammande name i want to execute .

Comment: Why do you need to include the cmd part at all, why don't you just launch "gcc ...."